# HTTP callout In Vlocity integration procedure

Tags: integration, soap, vlocity

I have a Vlocity integration Procedure where I call a SOAP web Service.
When the reponse of the HTTP has the code 500, it's not possible to use that  response on the following steps of the Integration procedure.
do you have any idea about how i can go to the following steps of my integration or use the response of the HTTP Action .
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Method 1-
Fail On Step Error: If this option is enabled in any step of the integration procedure then the Integration Procedure terminates if that particular step fails.
So, to proceed to the next steps of the integration procedure, simply disable the checkbox - fail on step error on your HTTP action. Also, you can then use this response on the following steps of the integration procedure. For e.g. - say after this HTTP action you have a response action. You can give any node name in the Response JSON Node of the HTTP action and use the same node in your response action's Send JSON path.

Method 2 -
You can use a try catch block.
Drag a Try-Catch Block into the Structure panel and make sure its Fail on Block Error checkbox is checked. Configure the "catch" behavior — what the Try-Catch Block will do if a failure occurs. For this, under Failure Response, specify a key-value pair to return as the response. The value can be a formula. In Spring '20 and later releases, the value can include merge fields. Now, drag HTTP Action into the Try-Catch Block, and make sure the Fail on Step Error checkbox is checked for your HTTP action which will trigger the "catch" behavior if it fails. Also, you can then use this response on the following steps of the integration procedure.

Answer (score -1):

Hello when you are in an Integration Procedure and you want **to use the return of an HTTP ACTION** (not talking about the actual Response Body but all the other information including **HTTP Request Status and statusCode**) :

**Please make sure to use the name of the HTTP ACTION + Info Ex:**

1. **Name of HTTP ACTION =** `GetPrices`
2. **Variable to use after calling the HTTP ACTION :** `GetPricesInfo`

`GetPricesInfo` contains the status of the HTTP action and the `statusCode` and other information. `(status :"OK",statusCode :200)`.
You can use it this way : `GetPricesInfo:status` or `GetPricesInfo:statusCode`.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Different forums and sites have different rules, culture and mores. While we do want and prefer questioners to accept answers, here on SFSE it is frowned upon and considered poor etiquette to prompt for having your answer upvoted or marked as best. When I edited your answer I removed that line.

Comment: Thank you ! I just had same issue yesterday and wanted to make sure others will benefit from this information because its not mentionned over the documentation of Vlocity.